# Combinations with a conditional function for combining every 2 elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, constraints, combinations

I have an array of (max 40) components `['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5',...]` and:

- I need to produce a new array containing combinations of r = 2, 3 and 4
- but some specific components cannot ever be in the same combination.

I have a function that can `verify_combination(component1,component2)` by consulting a database table. It will return `False` if it's a forbidden combination. If I assumed combining (c1,c3) is forbidden, as well as (c4,c5), in the end I'd have something like this:

```
combinations = [(c1,c2),(c1,c4),(c1,c5),(c2,c3),(c2,c4),(c2,c5),(c3,c4),(c3,c5), (c1,c2,c4),(c1,c2,c5),(c2,c3,c4),(c2,c3,c5)]
    
# (I believe that's right)
# (In this case no valid combinations of r=4 would be produced)
```

I'm not very experienced with python and programming overall, and I seriously lack the math skills to model this *combination with criteria or condition*. I have tried to do so for the last few hours, tried to find code like this already written on web, and also tried to around with itertools, but not even near the solution.

Comment: useful to say *"with the **constraints** that (c1,c3) and (c4,c5) can't be combined"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I'd probably start with itertools.combinations, which will return an iterable of the members of the input list. Then you can filter out the illegal combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations as combos, chain
from functools import filter

pairs = filter(verify_combination, combos(input_list, 2))
triples = filter(verify_combination, combos(input_list, 3))
quads = filter(verify_combination, combos(input_list, 4))

combined_combos = list(chain(pairs, triples, quads))
```

Comment: Indeed forming the lists first and then filtering out illegal combinations seems the way to go, but I'll be using a for loop. Your method is way more elegant, but I couldn't manage to find out 1- how to pass two parameters for verify_combination function on filter() 2-even if I did, I wouldn't know how to make it so that each 2 of every 3r and 4r combinations was checked and filtered out if illegal relation was detected. Thanks a lot anyhow, moving forward :D

Comment: To be sure, this approach doesn't _form the lists first_. It creates lazy iterables, not eager lists. Your `verify_combination` should take a single argument: a tuple of 2, 3 or 4 members. (You could also use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), but don't.)

Comment: But all that said, there's nothing inherently wrong with using a `for` loop here. For a very, very large data set I tend to push back against aggregations (building up a list by looping over something and using .append a lot) but I'm sure it's fine here.